# Search button wont fetch results Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

This my html file

```
<div id="app1" v-cloak>
        <input v-model="term" type="search">
        <button @click="search">Search</button>
        <p/>
            <div v-for="post in posts" class="post">
                    <p><strong>@{{post.title}}</strong></p>
                    <p>@{{post.body}}</p  
                    <br clear="left">
                </div>
</div>
```

this is my app.js file

```
const app1 = new Vue({
    el:'#app1',
    data:{
        term:'',
        posts:[],
        noResults:false,
        searching:false
    },
    methods:{
        search:function() {
        const url = `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${encodeURIComponent(this.term)}` ;
            fetch(url)
            .then(res => res.json())
            .then(res => {this.posts = res.posts;})
        }
    }
  });
```

How can i make that when search button is pressed with value, search results are appending to post class? From chrome dev tools in network, results are showing correctly but they wont show on my page, How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

Your last line should be:

```
.then(posts => this.posts = posts)
```

```js
const app1 = new Vue({
  el:'#app1',
  data: {
    term:'',
    posts:[],
    noResults:false,
    searching:false
  },
  methods:{
    search: function() {
      const url = `http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/${encodeURIComponent(this.term)}` ;
       fetch(url)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(posts => this.posts = posts)
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="app1" v-cloak>
 <input v-model="term" type="search">
 <button @click="search">Search</button>
 <p/>
    <div v-for="post in posts" class="post">
      <p><strong>@{{post.title}}</strong></p>
      <p>@{{post.body}}</p>  
      <br clear="left">
    </div>
</div>
```

---